# CIVL detects data race in OpenMP program - is it correct?

Tags: c, openmp, verification

I run **CIVL** with the command `civl verify -input_omp_thread_max=2 file.c`, and it detected a defect in the program. The warning is:

> Thread 1 can't perform $omp_write because thread 0 has written to the same variable and hasn't flushed yet.

But I can't understand it. I thought it may be because the global variant `sum` should be added to `flush`, but after I do it, the warning is still exist. I am puzzled whether there is a defect in the program as the warning shows. Thanks for your help.

The OpenMP program is in the following:

```
#define N 100

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

double a[N], b[N];
double localsum, sum = 0.0;
int i, tid, nthreads;

#pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,sum) private(i, localsum)
{
  /* Initialization */
  #pragma omp for
  for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    a[i] = b[i] = (double)i;

  localsum = 0.0;

  /* Compute the local sums of all products */
  #pragma omp for 
  for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    localsum = localsum + (a[i] * b[i]);

  #pragma omp critical //add flush(sum) is useless
  sum = sum+localsum;

 }  /* End of parallel region */

  printf("   Sum = %2.1f\n",sum);
  assert(sum==328350);

  exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. There is an implicit flush at the beginning and end of a `critical` region. CIVL seems to be in error, although I cannot reproduce it.

That said, in practice - use a reduction as provided by OpenMP instead of reinventing that.